# Sound is not working in Ubuntu 14.04: suddenly stopped

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, audio

The sound suddenly stopped working in my Ubuntu, so I googled and followed [this link](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) but it doesn’t work to me.

Output of `aplay -l`:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog[ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: ALC662 rev1 Digital [ALC662 rev1 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Output of `cat /proc/asound/version`:

```
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k3.13.0-24-generic.
```

Output of `alsamixer`

[image]

Screenshot of the Systems Settings window which shows that the Sound icon does not appear under the **Hardware** heading, and most of the other icons are also missing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have your system setting issue however I had the sound issue and I tried everything that was ever recommended online, I was only able to fix my PC sound issue by running the following commands:

```
killall pulseaudio
rm -r ~/.config/pulse/*
rm -r ~/.pulse*
```

Some directories may not exist, that is OK.

then:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

**then reboot**

I found this solution [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure), there are also some other recommended solutions if this doesn't work.